# how to use transition in CSS and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I want to create a navbar with HTML and CSS and I want when I hover my mouse cursor over each item , a little line would appear bellow the items (like border-bottom) with a 0.2s transition. and I want the line appears from right to left
I searched and I found that I should use this code:

```
transition : width time ;
```

like

```
transition : width 0.2s ;
```

but when I use this code the "width" is not working and its undefined.
can u help me with it ?

```css
body
{
    background-color: gray;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}
ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: 90%;
    
}
li
{
float: left;
transition:width 0.2s;  
}
li a 
{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    
}
.searchbtn
{
    float: right;
}
li:hover
{
background-color: rgb(43, 43, 43) ;
border-bottom: 3px solid white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="icon/x-type" href="IMG/fav.png">
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li class="searchbtn"><a  href="#">Search</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately we can't animate (or set) the *width* of a border. So we'll need another way.

With CSS you can create [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements), like `::before` and `::after` to create blocks inside of another element. For your case we can use either of the aforementioned pseudo-elements to create a *border like* bar at the bottom of each `li`.
This bar can then be animated like a regular HTML element. This means that we can change the width, height, color, etc, but still make it look like a border.

In the example below I've used the `::after` psuedo element on your `li` elements to create the border like element in your list items. I've use `::after` because the border needs to be *after* the content in the `li`.

The element starts with a [`scaleX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scaleX()) transformation which manipulates the horizontal size of the pseudo-element. Whenever you hover, the `scaleX` is restored to the full width.
The reason for using `transform` instead of `width` is that `transform` is optimized for transitions and animations, though there is no law against transitioning `width` instead.

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: 90%;
}

li {
  /**
   * This needs to be position: relative so that the ::after element
   * will stay be relative to the size of this element.
   * Try to remove it and see what happens.
   */
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  transition: border-color 0.2s;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(43, 43, 43);
}

li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}

li::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  transform-origin: right center;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 0.2s;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}

li:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.searchbtn {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="icon/x-type" href="IMG/fav.png">
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    <li class="searchbtn"><a href="#">Search</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

On a sidenote: you're using some old techniques, like `float`, to position your elements. These techniques have been surpassed by [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) and [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) which give you more (and better) control over layouts. So I'd recommend that you study the two links above and find a more up-to-date tutorial (YouTube is covered in them about Flexbox and Grid) on creating layouts.

Answer (score 2):

The transition to the width is not doing anything because you are never changing the width of the "li" element.
The way the "transition" property works is by animating changes in the property you select.
If you want to change the text color on hover and have a nice transition, you could do something like this:

```
span {
  color: #000;
  transition: color 0.2s;
}

span:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}
```

I think you could use the ["after" pseudo selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) to achieve what you want by emulating a bottom border. Since you can't modify the length of the border directly.

[Here's a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/05drhgzq/3/)